# Python Module imports in Terminal but not through Unix Shell

Tags: python, terminal, pythonpath

I'm just getting started with Python and need a little guidance.

I'm using a Mac, but I have a python.org build of python installed as well as the original Apple install.

I'm trying to load up some 3rd party modules. When I run the script in IDLE or through Terminal, everything works fine. When I try to run it as a CRON job, I get an error saying it can't find the 3rd party module.

After some poking around, I've been lead to believe it's the PYTHONPATH / sys.path. I created a test script to show me my path. So why do I get different paths when it's run through terminal window versus directly as a shell script?

My two questions are:

1. Why are they different?
2. How can I get the direct shell process to find the 3rd Party Modules?

Here's my sys.path output when I run it in Terminal:

```
['/Library/Scripts',
 '/Library/Scripts/$',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python27.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

Here's my sys.path output when I run it in the shell (in this case I'm in Applescript with a "do shell script" step.

```
"['/Library/Scripts',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']"
```

Comment: You should definitely look into virtualenv; it will help you juggle different versions of python and project-specific path variables.

Answer (score 4):

> Why are they different?

Because you're running two different Python interpreters, and they have different default `sys.path` values.

That's on purpose—it's what allows you to modify the standard (or site) library of your Python.org installation, without breaking the system installation (or any of the Apple-supplied tools that depend on that installation).

I'm guessing that when you run `python` in a Terminal, you're getting `/usr/local/bin/python` (you can check that by typing `which python`), which is presumably a link to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/bin/python` (or possibly to a `Python.app/Contents/MacOS/python` somewhere inside that framework). And that Python, from python.org, is compiled to set up `sys.path` around /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/.

Meanwhile, when you run `python` via Launch Services, you're probably getting `/usr/bin/python`, which is (hopefully) the built-in shim around `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`, which is compiled to set up `sys.path` around `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/`.

The reason `python` does different things in those cases is that `/usr/local/bin` is not on your login `PATH` at all, but is added to the head of the path by a line in your `~/.profile` (or other) file. That file is read by shell sessions in Terminal, but not by Launch Services sessions.

If you want to use the same Python in all environments, you could explicitly run `/usr/local/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/python` instead of just `python`. (You could also get `/usr/local/bin` onto your login PATH, but that's a very bad idea, or get it out of your `~/.profile`, but that's a little inconvenient.)

As a side note, this is a sign that your python.org installation is very broken:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python27.zip
```

There is no Python 7.3. I'd strongly consider uninstalling and reinstalling the python.org build.

Or, more simply, uninstall it and leave it uninstalled, and just use the built-in Python 2.7. If you want multiple environments, use `virtualenv` instead of multiple installations. If, e.g., Apple's giving you 2.7.2 and you really really need 2.7.3, then you need another installation; otherwise, you're just making things harder for no benefit.

Comment: BTW, I believe that the `7.3` framework version above is from an Enthought Python OS X distribution, not a broken installation.  They used their own framework version scheme to co-exist with python.org Pythons.